# Download thumbnail of file from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I can download the original file from Google Drive by using the following code :

```
public static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file)
            throws IOException {
        if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
            try {
                HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory()
                        .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                        .execute();
                return resp.getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // An error occurred.
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But it looks like the connection really low when downloading many files to add into the grid view.

Therefore, I need to list thumb nail instead of original file as it will be better for the connection.

Please help me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [File.getThumbnail](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getThumbnail%28%29) method to get the thumbnail or [File.getIconLink](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getIconLink%28%29) to get the icon link.

Comment: Thanks, I use File.getIconLink is successful, but I want to get Thumbnail. And i got problem, please see here to get it in more detail. [File.getThumnail is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674008/android-google-drive-set-thumbnail-for-image-file)

Comment: @mirror towers : you need to call File.getThumnailLink (as per iOS API)

Comment: This is the old V2 api, is there an equivalent in V3?