# Set thumbnail image for uploading on Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I use the following code to **set thumb nail for file to upload** on Google Drive :

```
// Set thumb nail path                  
String thumbnail_path = mediaContent.getFile().getAbsolutePath();   
// thumbnail_path : "/sdcard/Picture/ds01.jpg" 

// File's meta data.                    
File body = new File();                 
body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());                   
body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

// Thumb nail                   
final Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail();                    
thumbnail.setMimeType("image/jpeg");            

// UPDATE HERE : define byte array
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(getData(thumbnail_path));  
thumbnail.encodeImage(Base64.encodeBase64String(data));

// set thumb nail for file
body.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
```

The code run successful, but I think something wrong, i don't know where.
Because I used following code to get information related to file, and the **file.getThumbnail() is null**. (*getTitle() and getMimeType() is successful*).

```
private static void printFile(Drive service, String fileId) {
        try {
            File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

            System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
            System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());
            System.out.println("getThumbnail: " + file.getThumbnail());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
        }
    }
```

The following code is for uploading, it successful :

```
String folderId = ManageFile.getIdLink();
Log.d(TAG, "folderId " + folderId);
body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(folderId)));

File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

**UPDATE :**
- I add those code for describe how to get byte array.

```
protected byte[] getData(String thumbnail_path) {
        byte[] imageData = null;
        final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 96;

        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(thumbnail_path);

            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

            // byte data array
            imageData = baos.toByteArray();

            return imageData;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

p/s : 
- [Get file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it)
- [File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource)

Please tell me how to **get Thumb nail image successful**.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You decode the data from the `getData` method that are not encoded.

You should also use `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString` instead of `Base64.encodeBase64String`. You can use [File.Thumbnail.encodeImage](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.Thumbnail.html#encodeImage%28byte%5B%5D%29) method as a convenience. That will do the encoding for you.

Replace this:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(getData(thumbnail_path));  
thumbnail.setImage(Base64.encodeBase64String(data));
```

with this:

```
byte[] data = getData(thumbnail_path);  
thumbnail.encodeImage(data);
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code will show the warning : "Invalid value for : Not a valid base64 byte string". If used my code, the warning does not show.

Comment: @AlexTran I am sorry, I misread the code. I edited my answer.

Comment: Really thanks for your effort, your code is good, ok, but i get [another error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721109/thumbnail-image-is-null-when-listing-file-from-google-drive)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the Base64 encoded image content instead of the path.

```
final Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail();                    
thumbnail.setMimeType("image/jpeg");            
thumbnail.setImage(base64encodedContent);
```

Comment: Thanks for "base64encodedContent" comment. I updated my question, please check it for new error (file.getThumbnail() is null), please help me.