# Thumbnail image is null when listing file from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

[I set the thumbnail successfull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674008/set-thumbnail-image-for-uploading-on-google-drive)

**In the same activity,** I used following code to get information related to file, and the **file.getThumbnail() show encoded data**, you know.

```
private static void printFile(Drive service, File file) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
    System.out.println("getThumbnail: " + file.getThumbnail());
}
```

**But in another activity** (I use intent to transfer), **when I list folder from Google Drive, file.getThumbnail() always null** (use method printFile() again). *I don't know why?*
The following code is for **listing files from specified folder**, it successfull :

```
private void listFile(final Drive service, final String folderId) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Files.List request;
            try {
                request = service.files().list();
                // Set id of the specified folder
                request.setQ(folderId);
                do {
                    try {
                        FileList fileList = request.execute();
                        request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());

                        // Implement : get list of files
                        for (File file : fileList.getItems()) {
                            printFile(service, file);

                            // TODO Get thumb nail in here
                            InputStream is = 
                                    downloadThumbnailFile(ManageFileDriveActivity.mDriveService, file); 
                             // We don't need note this method, because file.getThumnail() currently is null                            
                        }
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        request.setPageToken(null);
                    }
                } while (request.getPageToken() != null
                        && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
            } catch (final IOException e1) {
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

p/s : 
- [Get file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it)
- [File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource)

Please tell me how to **get Thumb nail image successful**.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Use the following code, the good solution :

```
public static InputStream downloadThumbnailFile(Drive service, File file)
        throws IOException {
    if (file.getThumbnailLink() != null && !file.getThumbnailLink().isEmpty()) {
        try {
            System.out.println("getThumbnailLink: " + file.getThumbnailLink());
            HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory()
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getThumbnailLink()))
                    .execute();

            return resp.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file.getThumbnailLink()`. `thumbnail` attribute is write-only.